# How can I have a CloudFlare worker respond to incoming HTTP requests from users?

Tags: javascript, dns, cloudflare-workers

I have written a CloudFlare worker in JavaScript, matching the URL:

`example.com/blog/*`

Where `example.com` is an actual domain.

However I also have a `CNAME` record on CloudFlare for example.com (in CloudFlare) pointing `example.com` to the sites actual host.

My understanding (and testing confirms this) is that, after resolving DNS, users will send their HTTP requests straight to the sites host - so the CloudFlare worker will never get called.

I've investigated the [CloudFlare workers docs](https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/starters) and they don't seem to cover this point.

**How can I have a CloudFlare worker respond to incoming HTTP requests from users?**

Comment: I suspect I may need CloudFlare in proxy mode (vs DNS only) but would love a link to some official docs on the subject before making large scale changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your DNS settings, you need to make sure the hostname is set to "proxied" mode. It should look like this:

[image]

In this mode, your DNS will resolve to Cloudflare's IP. Requests will go to Cloudflare first. If they match your worker path, they'll go to the worker, otherwise they will go on to the CNAME target.

Comment: Thanks Kenton. I discovered this myself (wish the docs had made it more explicit) but it seems fair to award the point to someone else!